# How to efficiently use handlers in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, handler

I have recently started learning Swift and the Xcode documentation. Nonetheless, I am facing quite some problems with the handlers in general as seen in the code below:

```
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
    // Delete the row from the data source
    self.restaurantNames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.restaurantLocations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.restaurantTypes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.restaurantIsVisited.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.restaurantImages.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    // Call completion handler with true to indicate
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

I don't quite understand why did the tutorial that I am following (which is appcoda) has written `(action, sourceView, completionHandler)`. For better understanding I tried changing this tuple to `(action, sourceView, completionHandler)` and it yielded the same result, which surprised me a lot. Therefore I wanted to ask you, what should I put inside these tuples and what is there purpose?

Comment: It's a closure. Check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: yup, that's called a closure in Swift

Comment: I don't want to suggest an edit because it'll probably get rejected in review, but I'm pretty sure those variable names that were "corrected" in revision 2 were intentionally misspelled.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes they were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the parameters for your closure that you get when the `completionHandler` is called. This is what they are:

**action:**

> The object containing information about the selected action.

**sourceView:**

> The view in which the action was displayed.

**completionHandler:**

> The handler block for you to execute after you have performed the
>   action. This block has no return value and takes the following
>   parameter: **actionPerformed**
>   A Boolean value indicating whether you performed the action. Specify
>   true if you performed the action or false if you were unable to
>   perform the action for some reason.

Reference and more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextualaction) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextualactionhandler).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, though we when I changed the naming it didn't change the output?

Comment: No they wont, each parameter has it´s position but you can name them as you want. A recommendation is to use the names above though for clarification.

Comment: Oh, I see though we didn't we precise the fourth parameter in the closure? ( and is it normal that we do not refer to any of the four throughout the code)

Comment: oh ok I see so the actionPerformed is inside the completionHandler one, though why do we declare them if we don't use them throughout the code?

Comment: These are used in some cases in the completion block. If you don´t want to use any of them you could declare them with an underscore `_` instead. Like this: `let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (_, _, completionHandler) in ... }`

Comment: you are facing various problems @Fozoro - I would honestly recommend you don't bother with a complicated contextual action approach on UI elements.  It is so, so, simple to just call a function from your button, text field or whatever.  Then, learn about closures!  Then maybe look in to functional programming, etc etc.

Comment: @Fattie Yeah, I understand the big picture ( on how to make the things working ) but I get easily frustrated when I don't understand how some things work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! upvoted and checked your answer! the link that you have sent doesn't appear to work

Comment: @Fozoro, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) are the link. Np glad to help, good luck with your programming.